# Подскажите скрипт Jquery прокрутки страницы от блока к блоку

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools, плагин, javascript

Подскажите скрипт Jquery прокрутки страницы от блока к блоку, когда нажимая на меню вверху - плавно переносит на блок, соответствующий выбранному меню

Comment: scrollTo    []()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Посмотрите здесь](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/)

[Еще вариант](http://www.howtomake.com.ua/front/plavnaya-navigaciya-na-stranice.html)

Также плавный переход по якорю

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('a[href*=#]').bind("click", function(e){
            var anchor = $(this);
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $(anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 100
        }, 2000);
        e.preventDefault();
        });
        return false;
});
```

Comment: @soledar10 вы у них на зарплате что-ли ?

Comment: это всего лишь совпадение